# How to format this date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have XML file and bunch of datetime values in it. The example of these values: 20090128T103511,68+01

What format is this? And how can I parse it in c# to a DateTime ??

Comment: Have you tried using `DateTime.Parse`?

Comment: Posix TimeStamp I believe

Comment: Is the use of `,` even correct? If it's an international datetime, it should use `.`

Comment: If it is Unix time, its format is wrong, right? It should be yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss, and the part after the comma I do not get. What I can say is, that this executes: DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("2009-01-28T10:35:11");

Comment: @KaiHartmann I see everyone (me too) do the same error:  yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss ... 24h not 12h :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `DateTime.ParseExact("20090128T103511,68+01", "yyyyMMddTHHmmss,ffzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Note that the `DateTime` will be converted to your local timezone (so if you aren't +01 the hour you receive from the `DateTime.ParseExact` will be different-but-equivalent to the one in the string... Try changing the values of the timezone and see)

If you need here there are the various format specifiers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: I think it should be `HH` (24-hour) instead of `hh` (12-hour)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit And I make this error every time :-(

Comment: Thanks, this works. I didn't have this: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture